# Hints for debugging bokeh

Tags: bokeh

My app has become fairly complex, about 1500 lines across several files. There is a button that creates tabs and adds them to an existing panel. Here is a minimal working example of how the button works:

```py
def create_new_tab():
    paragraph = Paragraph(text="Hello!")
    tab = Panel(child=paragraph, title="tab")
    tab.closable = True
    return tab

def append_new_tab():
    new_tab = create_new_tab()
    curdoc().select_one({'name': 'tabs'}).tabs.append(new_tab)

button = Button(label='append new tab')
button.on_click(append_new_tab)

tab1 = Panel(child=button, title='button tab')
tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab1], name='tabs')
curdoc().add_root(tabs)
```

In my actual program there is a bug somewhere, because when I click the button I get the message that some set changed during iteration:

> error handling message Message 'EVENT' (revision 1) content: '{"event_name":"button_click","event_values":{"model_id":"1002"}}': RuntimeError('Set changed size during iteration',)

I have spent some time trying to debug, without success. I have tried to create a minimal not working example, but all my minimal examples work. I keep staring at the error message and wonder what else can I do to find out what is going wrong?

Remark: I am already using `bokeh serve myapp/ --dev`

Comment: I think this is already fixed for a next release https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/8837
I have the error myself in an app but it does not seem to do anything

Comment: you are right, there is no dysfunction of my program either.

Answer (score 2):

You can debug your app using this code (Bokehh v1.1.0):

```
from bokeh.models import Panel, Tabs, Button, Paragraph
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler

def modify_doc(doc):

    def create_new_tab():
        paragraph = Paragraph(text="Hello!")
        tab = Panel(child=paragraph, title="tab")
        tab.closable = True
        return tab

    def append_new_tab():
        new_tab = create_new_tab()
        doc.select_one({'name': 'tabs'}).tabs.append(new_tab)

    button = Button(label='append new tab')
    button.on_click(append_new_tab)

    tab1 = Panel(child=button, title='button tab')
    tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab1], name='tabs')
    doc.add_root(tabs)

io_loop = IOLoop.current()
server = Server(applications = {'/app': Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))}, io_loop = io_loop, port = 5001)
server.start()
server.show('/app')
io_loop.start()
```

Comment: I am not sure how this helps me with debugging but I didn't know that I could start the app in this way.

Comment: is there an option to see the full error trace? messages of the above type are usually to unspecific to find out what's going on.

Comment: Running Bokeh server with this code allows you to set a `breakpoint` to inspect your variables and go step by step into Bokeh method that gives you an error or a warning. I am really surprised I have to explain to a programmer what debugging and breakpoints mean...

Comment: i didn't make that connection. I'll check it out.

Comment: I have created a `debug.py` which is a copy of the `main.py` but with the modifications suggested above. I can set breakpoints and start debugging. The plots are not visible in the browser which is correct in this setup, right?